# When I start my program (Selenium) it opens web page then it closes immediately after whithout error in log

Tags: python, selenium

My code is very short. When I try it, the program opens web page but program closes immediately after.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

I believe the problem is coming from my environment, so I have not tried any changes to the code to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the below chrome options:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get("https://google.com")
```